# For a bigger-than-memory dask array of size=(M, N): How to re-chunk from chunks=(1, N) to chunks=(M, 1)?

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

In order to, e.g., apply an IIR-Filter coded in Numpy/Numba along a whole axis, I need to re-chunk a `size=(M, N)` dask-array from `chunks=(m0, n0)` to `chunks=(m1, N)` with `m1 < m0`.

As Dask avoids repeating tasks, during rechunk-split/rechunk-merge, it will have data worth `(m0, N)` (x 2?) in memory.  Is there a way of optimizing the graph to avoid this behaviour?

I know where to find info on optimizing Dask graphs by hand.  But is there a way of either tweaking the scheduling policy to allow for repeating tasks or to (automatically) re-arrange the graph in order to minimize memory use during this rechunk?

Here's a minimal example (for the extreme case where `chunks=(M, 1)` → `chunks=(1, N)`):

```py
from dask import array as da
from dask.distributed import Client

# limit memory to 4 GB
client = Client(memory_limit=4e9)

# Create 80 GB random array with chunks=(M, 1)
arr = da.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=(1e5, 1e5), chunks=(1e5, 1))

# Compute mean (This works!)
arr.mean().compute()

# Rechunk to chunks=(1, N)
arr = arr.rechunk((1, 1e5))

# Compute mean (This hits memory limit!)
arr.mean().compute()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you're in a worst-case situation, you'll need to compute every input chunk before you can get a single output chunk.

Dask's rechunking operations are decent, and they'll rechunk things into blocks of intermediate size in the interim, so it's possible that this would work in less-than-full memory, but you'll definitely be writing things to disk.

In short, in principle there is nothing that you should be doing extra.  In theory Dask's rechunking algorithms should handle this.  If you wanted to you could play with the `threshold=` and `block_size_limit=` keywords to rechunk.

Comment: Is there any way of allowing for a repetition of tasks?  As far as I understand, Dask will try hard not to repeat anything.  Say, for each output chunk, compute all input chunks, keep what you need for the current chunk, throw away everything not needed.

(I think about situations like the one in <http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/setup/hpc.html#no-local-storage> where all I have is memory and CPU.)

Comment: Unfortunately not today

Answer (score 0):

The `block_size_limit=` keyword lead to sort of a solution.

(Below, I use a smaller array, because I didn't have 80GB of disk left to spill to.)

```py
from dask import array as da
from dask.distributed import Client

# limit memory to 1 GB
client = Client(n_workers=1, threads_per_worker=1, memory_limit=1e9)

# Create 3.2 GB array
arr = da.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=(2e4, 2e4), chunks=(2e4, 1e1))

# Check graph size
print(len(arr.__dask_graph__()), "nodes in graph")  # 2000 nodes

# Compute
print(arr.mean().compute())  # Takes 11.9 seconds. Doesn't spill.

# re-create array and rechunk with block_size_limit=1e3
arr = da.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=(2e4, 2e4), chunks=(2e4, 1e1))
arr = arr.rechunk((2e1, 2e4), block_size_limit=1e3)

# Check graph size
print(len(arr.__dask_graph__()), "nodes in graph")  # 32539 nodes

# Compute
print(arr.mean().compute())  # Takes 140 seconds, spills ~5GB to disk.

# re-create array and rechunk with default kwargs
arr = da.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=(2e4, 2e4), chunks=(2e4, 1e1))
arr = arr.rechunk((2e1, 2e4))

# Check graph size
print(len(arr.__dask_graph__()), "nodes in graph")  # 9206 nodes

# Compute
print(arr.mean().compute())  # Worker dies at 95% memory use
```